# Debug Log shows Flows executing in a different order to Flow Trigger Explorer

Tags: visual-workflow, after-trigger, debugging, debug-logs, order-of-execution

Just wondering if someone can help me to understand what I'm seeing in our org. I'm trying to document the order in which our automation runs when a Lead is created. My problem is that I'm seeing flows executing in the Debug Log in a different order to the order that was set in Flow Trigger Explorer. It's actually the opposite (reverse order) of the order they've been set to execute in FTE. I must be reading the debug log wrong or something.

I don't want to post the whole debug log here but the order in which these after-save record-triggered flows appear in the debug log (with the FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN event then after they finish there's the FLOW_INTERVIEW_FINISHED event and all the details in between) are as follows:

1. Lead - After Trigger Flow - Sync Billing Addresses
2. Lead - After Trigger Flow – Notification
3. Lead - After Trigger – Account Round Robin
4. Lead Source Process (this is a Flow)

But here's a screenshot of the flows in Flow Trigger Explorer:
[image: Flows From Flow Trigger Explorer]

Both the debug log and the image come from our production instance. Is it possible for the debug log to show things in a different order from the order they've been set to run in? I didn't think so but I don't have a lot of experience of using debug logs.

Any more info you need, let me know. Can provide more log info if it helps.

Very grateful for any help you can give me.

All the best,

Matt

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. Excerpt the relevant sections of the debug log and add to OP (use [edit]. And keep it short

Comment: Please turn your comment into an answer. Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable here, and makes it easier for others to find/read (because of the extended length/formatting options). You'll also be able to accept your own answer (after an hour or a day, I forget which), which signals to the community that you don't need further help.

Answer (score 3):

Argh! Can't believe this. I've solved it. This is a misunderstanding caused by the layout of FTE. When I click the carret to the right of one of those after flows and click 'Flow Details And Versions' I can clearly see 'Trigger Order: Unspecified' in the pop-up layer on the right with details of the flow. Opening each flow and viewing their properties to check confirms that no trigger order has been set for any of them. They just appear with numbers in FTE which totally confused me.

Comment: Brilliant!   thank you for creating an answer